# PDF of sum of normal distribution with unknown mean

Tags: probability, distributions

Suppose I have a random variable $Z$ composed as a sum,
$$
Z = \frac{1}{2}X_1+ \frac{1}{2}X_2
$$
where $ X_1 \sim N(\theta_1,1) $ and $X_2 \sim N(\theta_1 + \theta_2,1)$ and $\theta_1, \theta_2$ are parameters

What would be the PDF/Likelihood of this random variable? Would it be simply the sum of the two individual PDF's?

Comment: Because your notation is ambiguous, please explain: are you summing *random variables* or *distribution functions??*

Comment: Edited, I meant random variables (I believe it's called a mixture model)

Comment: That's not a mixture model.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=mixture+pdf for mixtures.  This is a *linear combination* of random variables.  Its pdf is found with [convolution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=convolution%20sum%20score%3a5%20is%3aanswer%20-neural).  When the $X_i$ are independent, the calculation is dead simple because the linear combination also is Normal, so all you have to do is compute its mean and variance.  Otherwise you need to specify their full joint distribution in order to obtain an answer.

Comment: @shem You edited the question body but the title needs to change as well. Please fix; you aren't summing or averaging distributions. Also beware of calling an average a sum; the two are very closely related but they're not the same thing.

Comment: Thousands of posts here on CV show how to find the distribution of $Z.$ Among them, the duplicate helps us understand the distinction between sums of random variables and mixtures of distributions, a distinction that seems to be at the heart of this question.